# Cufon & jQuery addClass error

Tags: jquery, cufon

I have a simple unordered list with cufon text replacement, and I am using the following jQuery to addClass .selected (which basically highlights the most recently clicked list item) and also removes the classes from the rest of the list items.

This works fine without the cufon and is pretty basic JS, but with the cufon it adds but does not remove the class.

I have tried changing to strict doctype which gets around certain cufon bugs, moving the code before and after the cufon calls, and amending the cufon code itself but still not getting anywhere any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ul#list li a").click(function() {
        $("ul#list li a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");       
    });

});
```

Comment: IMHO Cufon is not the best option for text replacement. Even on their website they say: `You might also want to take this opportunity to try Typekit, a hosted, @font-face-based alternative. Yes, that means they support text selection. It's the easiest way to embrace standards.`. My suggestion is to try [Typekit](http://http://typekit.com) or [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts)

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your response. I understand these other solutions are much better in general but in this case I need to be using cufon due to costs etc, I may just have to settle for a highlight on hover and no selected state if there is no other way around it.

Comment: Google fonts is free, and Typekit has a free option too (although limited). You could also (if you have the font downloaded and license permitting) host the font yourself and use `@font-face`. [An article on different methods with pro's and cons](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/typography-articles/a-web-designers-guide-to-font-replacement-methods/) - But back to your issue with Cufon, what is `$(this)` referring too? You can check with `alert($(this));` or `console.log($(this));` and check the console.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info, I had looked on Google Fonts and the font I needed wasn't available as is often the case there unforunately. 'this' referred to 'ul#list li a' in the code.. fairly basic stuff. Also will look into font-face as I have least experience with that. Cheers